# cmake installation, not founded library after installation

Tags: installation, cmake, dependencies, shared-libraries

I know there are sevareal answers about this topic, but certainly, I do not understand them.
[Linux | ubuntu 20.04 | cmake 3.23]
The problem is that while building a shared library with cmake, when I link this library to an executable, the library is founded [tested with ldd command]. But when i install the project my executable in /bin folder, cant find my library in lib directory.

The error is:

```
./my_executable.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libCOOK.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Program directory**

```
src/
    exes/
       my_exe.f90
    libraries/
       COOK.c
```

**Install directory**

```
-lib/
   libCOOK.so
-bin/
    my_executable.exe
-include/
```

Comment: "But when i install the project my executable in /bin folder, cant find my library in lib directory." - Too vague description of the problem. Please, add to the question post the **code** (in form of [mcve]) and the **error message** which you got.

Comment: In the build directory CMake handles RPATH settings automaticall. When install your artifacts, you should adjust RPATH by yourself. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that i should added just before building the object, if you add at the start of the compilation file (before enabling language, find anything and that stuff) it becomes erased after. Your answer make  guided me where i had to look.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer:
Just add the install_directory/lib to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH